# Google maps api - strange div over map

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3

I added map to my website, but something is wrong with it. This is what happens...

[image]

This is html

```
<div id='map'>

    </div>
        <script async defer
                src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDNnZ9kGQCZbjbUAceQXwxW9TBHxV2tNlU&callback=initMap"></script>
```

and this is my JS code...

```
function initMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 15.177076, lng: 15.619812},
    zoom: 8
  });
  }
```

I have also find out that this white div is under the class 'gmnoprint', and I have set *display: none* for that class. Behind that element there is an *div* element which contains link to google maps.

That div is also all over my map, and it blocks me to control the map, but it doesn't contain class or id attribute.

What is the problem? If there is no other solution, what is the way I could change that element style (what CSS selectors should I use)?

It looks like this...

[image]

Comment: Really weird. Do you have a complete code sample to reproduce this?

Comment: All code for the map is here. I managed to fix this issue by hiding first white div and setting `height: auto; width: auto` for the second div which contains google link (div height and width is set by height and width of google link). Still don't know what is the problem, but I found the way to avoid it

Comment: It's really strange, because I can see the Google icon in the top left corner. It must be in the bottom left corner. As far as I know it's prohibited to change position of the attribution according to the ToS. Are you sure that you don't override default styles?

Comment: Yes I'm totally sure. After I added style `width: auto; height: auto` for div (that contains google link), google link positions in the bottom left corner

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/google_maps_basic.asp

Try this. It worked for me.

It's a faster way of adding a map to your site. 
Same functions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue.

I found out it was in my css.

I had a rule that applied to all div nested into two elements like so:

```
anElement AnOtherElement div
{    
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}
```

And this div was nested into these two elements so the rules applied and it streched this div and another one to the top of the map.

[Streched div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOnEr.png)